# How make aggregation java8 with specific condition

Tags: java, java-8

I'd like to make aggregation of the following example:

I have a `List<CsvEntity> toSort =` of entities as described below:

```
toSort.add(new CsvEntity(...))..

public class CsvEntity {
    String OCCURRENCES, STATUS, MESSAGE, STACK_TRACE;
}
```

The data:

```
  OCCURRENCES,   STATUS,MESSAGE,STACK_TRACE   
    1,       FAIL, MESSAGE1, STACK1
    1,       PASS, MESSAGE1, STACK1
    1,       FAIL, MESSAGE1, STACK1
    1,       FAIL, MESSAGE2, STACK2 => aggregate MESSAGE & STACK_TRACE)
    1,       PASS, MESSAGE2, STACK2
    1,       PASS, MESSAGE3, STACK3
    1,       PASS, MESSAGE3, STACK3
```

the result should be (as data structure):

```
OCCURRENCES,STATUS,MESSAGE,STACK_TRACE
3, FAIL, MESSAGE1, STACK1
2, FAIL, MESSAGE2, STACK2
2, PASS, MESSAGE3, STACK3
```

I tried to use:

```
Map<String, Integer> group = toSort.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        CsvEntity::getSTACK_TRACE, 
        Collectors.groupingBy(CsvEntity::getMESSAGE),
        Collectors.summingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.getOCCURRENCES()))
    )
);
```

but this group returns only the STACK_TRACE not the whole CsvEntity...

Is it possible and what to change in the code?

Comment: Are the members of `CsvEntity` supposed to be constants? If no, please don't name them using CAPS.

Comment: Or course it's possible. 1) define the correct grouping operator - you seem to want to group by message _and_ stack - so group by them concatenated. 2) define an appropriate downstream collector that stores the message and stack and has a counter you can increment and presumably does a logical and of the status.

Comment: can you give an example please :)

Comment: Also, what @lutzh said - use Java naming conventions. Variables are in camelCase.

Comment: And why `public class CsvEntity` and not `public enum CsvEntity` ?

Comment: @VitalyT why is the status here -> `2, FAIL, MESSAGE2, STACK2` as `FAIL`  instead of `PASS` ? what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: The logic very simple , it doesnt care which entity to display just to make aggregation by 2 fields  , it can be the 1st one , just return correct datastructure

Comment: For this logic/issue , it doesn't matter if it Camel case or not..suppose members of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my other answer, you could use the `groupingBy` collector but first I'd override `equals`/`hashcode` in the `CsvEntity` class as follows:

```
class CsvEntity {
     private String OCCURRENCES,STATUS,MESSAGE,STACK_TRACE;

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (this == o) return true;
         if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
         CsvEntity csvEntity = (CsvEntity) o;
         return Objects.equals(MESSAGE, csvEntity.MESSAGE) &&
                 Objects.equals(STACK_TRACE, csvEntity.STACK_TRACE);
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(MESSAGE, STACK_TRACE);
     }

     public CsvEntity(String OCCURRENCES, String STATUS, 
                  String MESSAGE, String STACK_TRACE) { ... }
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

Then the stream pipeline:

```
 List<CsvEntity> resultSet
                = source.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.summingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getOCCURRENCES()))))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(x -> {
                    CsvEntity c = x.getKey();
                    return new CsvEntity(Integer.toString(x.getValue()),
                          c.getSTATUS(), c.getMESSAGE(), c.getSTACK_TRACE());
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This again yields the following result:

```
[CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='3', STATUS='FAIL', MESSAGE='MESSAGE1', STACK_TRACE='STACK1'}, 
 CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='2', STATUS='FAIL', MESSAGE='MESSAGE2', STACK_TRACE='STACK2'}, 
 CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='2', STATUS='PASS', MESSAGE='MESSAGE3', STACK_TRACE='STACK3'}]
```

Comment: wow such an elegant solution , will check it soon :) , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of how you could group and aggregate the data. Hope this helps.

***Code***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CsvEntity> toSort = getToSort();

        Map<String, List<CsvEntity>> grouped = toSort.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.stackTrace));

        List<CsvEntity> aggregated = grouped.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    CsvEntity csvEntity = entry.getValue().get(0);
                    String occurrences = String.valueOf(entry.getValue().size());

                    return new CsvEntity(occurrences, csvEntity.status, csvEntity.message, csvEntity.stackTrace);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        aggregated.forEach(csvEntity -> System.out.println(csvEntity.toString()));
    }

    private static List<CsvEntity> getToSort() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new CsvEntity("1", "Fail", "Message 1", "Stack 1"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Pass", "Message 1", "Stack 1"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Fail", "Message 1", "Stack 1"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Fail", "Message 2", "Stack 2"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Pass", "Message 2", "Stack 2"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Pass", "Message 3", "Stack 3"),
                new CsvEntity("1", "Pass", "Message 3", "Stack 3")
        );
    }

    public static class CsvEntity {
        String occurrences;
        String status;
        String message;
        String stackTrace;

        CsvEntity(String occurrences, String status, String message, String stackTrace) {
            this.occurrences = occurrences;
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return occurrences + ", " + status + ", " + message + ", " + stackTrace;
        }
    }
```

***Output***

```
3, Fail, Message 1, Stack 1
2, Fail, Message 2, Stack 2
2, Pass, Message 3, Stack 3
```

Comment: Hi @VitalyT .. I misread the question. I've updated my code to only group on `stackTrace`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to accomplish the aforementioned result:

This uses @Boris the Spider's idea of concatenating the `message` and `stacktrace` properties for the value to "group by". Although, instead of using the `groupingBy` collector it might be better to use the `toMap` collector in this specific case.

```
List<CsvEntity> result = new ArrayList<>(source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getMESSAGE() + c.getSTACK_TRACE(),
                 v -> new CsvEntity(v.getOCCURRENCES(), v.getSTATUS(), v.getMESSAGE(), v.getSTACK_TRACE()),
                 (left, right) -> {
                     left.setOCCURRENCES(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(left.getOCCURRENCES())
                             + Integer.parseInt(right.getOCCURRENCES())));
                     return left;
                 }, LinkedHashMap::new))
        .values());
```

Note that this solution creates new `CsvEntity` objects with the new data but if you want to mutate the objects in the `source` list instead then simply change new `CsvEntity(v.getOCCURRENCES(), v.getSTATUS(), v.getMESSAGE(), v.getSTACK_TRACE())` to  `Function.identity()`.

Having executed this code, it yields the following result:

```
[CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='3', STATUS='FAIL', MESSAGE='MESSAGE1', STACK_TRACE='STACK1'}, 
 CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='2', STATUS='FAIL', MESSAGE='MESSAGE2', STACK_TRACE='STACK2'}, 
 CsvEntity{OCCURRENCES='2', STATUS='PASS', MESSAGE='MESSAGE3', STACK_TRACE='STACK3'}]
```

Comment: Do , I need to implement hashcode/equeals by 2 these properties ?    
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CsvEntity csvEntity = (CsvEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(getMESSAGE(), csvEntity.getMESSAGE()) &&
                Objects.equals(getSTACK_TRACE(), csvEntity.getSTACK_TRACE());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getMESSAGE(), getSTACK_TRACE());
    }

Comment: @VitalyT you could if you wanted to but with the current solution you need not. With the current solution, two objects are equal if they have the same `message` and `stacktrace` hence `c.getMESSAGE() + c.getSTACK_TRACE()`.